# Installing new OS on Powerbook G4 without USB key or CD

Tags: mac, boot, freebsd, powerpc, powerbook

I recently got a PowerBook G4 17" with a 1.67 GHz PowerPC CPU, 2GB of RAM, 100 GB of hard drive and running under OS X 10.5.8.

These computers are actually getting more and more obsolete, and this computer must be up to date concerning the software for a proper use (Mac OS X 10.5.8 can’t support the latest software since years).

I decided to install FreeBSD 10.1, which has a PPC version on this Mac. As I have no bootable CD’s, I decided to create a bootable USB key for installing the OS. To do so, I must burn the ISO into the USB key using software like [UNETbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net); this software doesn’t work with the old Mac because of its architecture so I had to use another computer to create my bootable USB key.

The problem is that I learned that PowerBook G4 does not accept USB booting, but I know you can install an OS directly from your computer using software like UNETbootin, but I have problems with software because of the Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can’t use UNETbootin because your system is out of date, instead of using UNETbootin—or similar packaged “Make a bootable USB” tools—you can create a bootable USB flash drive right from the command line in Terminal [as explained here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/howto-create-freebsd-usb-bootable-disk-from-a-mac.38774/). I am reworking those instructions because there are a few unclear/out-of-date things that should be ironed out. And why not clear that up here?

First, [download the appropriate Free BSD ISO](https://www.freebsd.org/where.html) from here. For this example I am downloading the `FreeBSD-10.1-RC3-powerpc-memstick.img` version of the image (which is the version tailored for USB flash drives) and saving it to the `~/Desktop`.

First, let’s open up the Terminal and go to the desktop like this:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Now, with the USB flash drive plugged into the computer run this command to get the filesystem name of the USB device:

```
df -h
```

For this example, let’s assume the device is named `disk1s1`. Now we’re going to unmount the USB flash drive from the command line like this:

```
sudo diskutil umount /dev/disk1s1
```

Okay, with `disk1s1` unmounted, run the [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) command to copy the contents of `FreeBSD-10.1-RC3-powerpc-memstick.img` to the USB flash drive on `/dev/disk1s1`:

```
sudo dd if="FreeBSD-10.1-RC3-powerpc-memstick.img" of="/dev/disk1s1" bs="10240"
```

Now wait for it to finish copying. And when that is done, you will have a  bootable USB flash drive with `FreeBSD-10.1-RC3-powerpc-memstick.img` on it.

And with that said, I realized that your PowerBook does not formally allow USB booting. So that alone won’t work, but [advice in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/19958/40457) as well as [on this page will help](http://lifedigital2010.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/how-to-install-mac-osx-from-usb-on-powerbook-g4/). And it boils down to following these two steps after creating the bootable USB flash drive:

1. Boot in the PowerBook OpenFirmware (the bootstrap that loads before Mac OS X) by pressing the <kbd>Apple</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keys at the same time right after you switch on the machine (before the chime sound).
2. Once in OpenFirmware enter this command: `boot usb1/disk@1:,\\yaboot`. If that somehow doesn’t work, you might be designating the incorrect `usb[x]/` path so try this one with `0` for `usb`: `boot usb0/disk@1:,\\yaboot`. The machine should reboot and you should be now booting off of the USB.

And if none of that seems to work, the [later page referenced above](http://lifedigital2010.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/how-to-install-mac-osx-from-usb-on-powerbook-g4/) seems to be a more succinct answer starting from item 4 in the list of instructions. Reproducing them here for clarity, formatting and reference:

4. Then you boot in the PowerBook OpenFirmware (the bootstrap that loads before Mac OS X) by pressing the <kbd>Apple</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keys at the same time right after you switch on the machine (before the chime sound)
5. Type `dev / ls` and try to find something like `/disk@1` next to an entry named USB (in my case `usb@1b,1`)
6. Type `DEVALIAS` in the command prompt and locate the short name of the USB entry you just found using `dev / ls` (in my case `usb0`)
7. Make sure your USB key holds a file called `BootX` with the `tbxi` attribute by listing the directory. In the following command, `disk@1` should be replaced by what you found in Step 5, also every character is important (this includes colon, forward slash, etc.). Type: `dir shortname_found_in_step_6/disk@1:partition_number_found_in_step_3,\System\Library\CoreServices` (in my case `dir usb0/disk@1:3,\System\Library\CoreServices`)
8. If `BootX` is found with an attribute called `tbxi` then you’re all set and you can instruct OpenFirmware to boot from the USB drive: `boot usb0/disk@1:3,\System\Library\CoreServices\BootX`
9. Hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and you should be booting from the USB drive. You can then install the operating system as you would with a DVD.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your instructions. The first 2 steps were OK for me. But I had to replace disk1s1 (in fact disk2s1 for me) with disk1 to flash my **whole** USB stick with a debian PPC image. And now my 2004 powerbook G4 is starting with a debian distro.